# Compare Oauth token with previously saved Token

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth-2.0

I'm working on a project where i'm currently trying to add an additional level of security. The idea is that when a Oauth token gets generated we compare it with one saved in our DB, if they don't match then the user is denied.   My problem is that i'm trying to do the comparison during the authentication flow right  before the token is given to the end user from the  /token endpoint, but I can't find where to access the generated token during the authentication request I only see it when the request is finally granted.  Just need a guide where "access_token" property is hiding at.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer fully without knowing what library you are using. If it's IdentityServer3 I'm not aware of a way to do this, but you shouldn't have to anyway for a couple reasons.

- Tokens shouldn't be issued until the user has been authenticated. Maybe I'm missing something, but I can't think of a circumstance when you would need to reject a user at this point.
- Every token should be unique, so you shouldn't expect to generate a token that already exists.

I also want to note that if you're using self contained tokens, there's no need to persist them since they can be validated using only the certificate's public key.

If you can clarify what you mean by additional security I could maybe come up with something more useful, but hopefully this is helpful anyway.

Comment: i'm using Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth on a web api platform.   Basically i'm trying to keep track of tokens so when a user is deleted or is in active that token will be cross reference with  onces that were saved previously.

Comment: Got it. I think my previous points still hold, but I think you could solve this differently. You configure `OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions` in startup class correct? It has a `Provider`option that appears you can implement to determine how authorization happens. If this is the case then you can just add a check there to see if the user is deleted or inactive (or any other custom logic) and return the desired response.I expect this happens before new tokens are generated, so no need for comparison to old tokens in this case (even though that should actually be impossible).